# How to revert to perspective transform?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I have a grouped shape (rectangular + some texts). I used the *Perspective* tool to make it align with the single-point perspective. But now I want to revert it back to a normal rectangle shape without perspective. But I could not do this by *right click →  transform → reset bounding box*.

What is the right way?

[image: Illustrator Screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately – as far as I know – there is no way to do this, since the Perspective tool is destructive and doesn’t allow you to revert objects to their original shape. I think the best solution would be to always keep a copy of the original shape just in case.

Comment: @mmxd thats not entirely true, you can by misake kill the link by manipulating the object. But you can indeed bring it back by manipulating the grid to be perpendicular to the screen, but that does not work for the ground plane, and its very very error prone.

Comment: @joojaa So Illustrator still does not have any tool or option to revert the perspective back?

Comment: Still? No the perspective toolset is one of those things that devs do to tick a checkbox, its just easier to avoid it entirely. Its more trouble than worth. I can draw perspective faster without it, if i could rip it out i would since it is a missclick waiting to happen

Comment: @joojaa Since Adobe has not implemented this feature even it is now almost 2018, will it be more efficient if I just manually draw some guidelines before transforming?

Comment: Adobe does not work that way, they do not fix omissions on a later date. Each project is its own and once a project finishes it will never get any attention, ever again. Either it works right the first time or it never will.

Comment: @joojaa That said, does any other tool has revert perspective feature? Like, does Affinity Designer do this? (I am new to this, and I have only tried Illustrator so far) Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69686/discussion-between-joojaa-and-jackxujh).

Answer (score 1):

This is not the real answer but it's a non-destructive way to work with perspectives.

1- Draw a grid and use the **Effect >> 3d >> Extrude & Bevel...**

2- Play with the values until you achieve the desired perspective and hit OK.

3- Now double-click the grid to enter **Isolation Mode**.

You will now start drawing in perspective.

You may notice that you can disable the effect at any moment using the **Appearance Panel.**

See the values I used in the image below:

[image]