# Traditional Drawing - Perspective Question

Tags: perspective

I am very new to drawing and currently studying all I can about perspective. I have a few things I like to ask that I am confused on.

Let's say I have drawn a cube in 1 point perspective.

How would I transfer that same cube (exact size/dimensions) into different other views in 1 point perspective.

How would I replicate the same size of the cube but in a different view?

When I do it sometimes my cube is smaller or sometimes it’s bigger than the cube I have previously drawn.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117014/at-what-point-does-1-point-perspective-become-2-point-perspective/117026#117026

Comment: I would understand this question if you did this for a 2 point or 3 poinyt perspective but for a 1 poinbt perspective theres only one thing to match

Answer (score 1):

[Foreshortening](https://drawpaintacademy.com/foreshortening/) may make objects appear to be different scales when they are not.

> Foreshortening in art refers to the way we perceive an object as it recedes in space.

Viewing angles can change the *perception* of size.

Comment: I also have another question: I draw a square plane down. Would I then draw the converging lines from the square plane towards the vanishing point or from the vanishing point towards the square? Which is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

The other views of the same cube in 1 point perspective imaging case can be got by moving the observer. If the imaging plane stays same (=in parallel with the front surface of the cube) the result is still 1-point perspective image.

1-point perspective imaging of a cube can be reversed - one can easily find a cube, an imaging plane and the placement of the observer (=the station point) which produce the given perspective image.

To solve your problem you should find the cube, station point and imaging plane which fit into your existing 1-point perspective image.

You have some freedom, perspective imaging isn't one-to-one math mapping. To keep everything simple you can assume the imaging plane is the front side of the cube.

Then you change the station point or the place of the cube and draw the new perspective image by inserting lines of sight.

A couple of methods to reverse 1-point perspective imaging of rectangular shapes are shown in this older case, where the questioner wanted to remove perspective and find the proportions of the original rectangles: [Finding proportions in perspective](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/133743/finding-proportions-in-perspective)